# pattern matching and replace function

Tags: python, regex, numpy

I am using regular expression to filter out the invalid values from a column. Is there any built-in function to replace the invalid value with the correct one using the regular expression. Lets try the example:

1. Regular Expression for Valid pattern  - `[0-9]{8}\s[A-Z]{2}`
2. Example value1 - `12345678AC` , which is the wrong one and the correct one is 
                   `12345678 AC` instead.
3. Example value2 - `12345678  AC 131`, which is also a wrong value and the
                   correct one is 12345678 AC.

Comment: How the numpy involves in this question?

Comment: Wait, what's the problem/question?

Comment: Well, there's `re.match` and `filter`. Put the two together and you have your answer. Except you don't really want to *filter out* the invalid items, you want to *amend* them, which makes me think that `map` is the appropriate choice, or whatever the equivalent is for the container type you're using.

Comment: Column of what?  If an array describe the shape and dtype.

Comment: I think you want a pattern that identifies 2 groups, the numeric one and the alpha one. You could then make a valid string by joining those 2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the '$' sign to mark the end of the statement.

Try this instead

```
import re
p = re.compile("^([0-9]{8}/s[A-Z]{2})$")
m = p.match(string)
```